# ClassCastException for the same class type in Spring-sync

Tags: java, spring, classcastexception, json-patch

I'm using [Spring-sync](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/22/introducing-spring-sync) as an implementation of `RFC 6902 (JSON Patch)`. The client side sends me a `JsonNode` representing the operations to apply on the server object.

My code is as following :

```
@PatchMapping(path = "/profile/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> patchUserProfile(@PathVariable Integer userId, @RequestBody JsonNode patchJsonNode) {

    JsonPatchMaker jsonPatchMaker = new JsonPatchMaker();
    Patch patch = jsonPatchMaker.fromJsonNode(patchJsonNode);

    UserProfileDto originalUserProfileDto = ...
    UserProfileDto patchedUser = patch.apply(originalUserProfileDto, UserProfileDto.class);

    userService.save(patchedUser);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(null);
}
```

I have an unexpected Java `ClassCastException` telling me that the object cannot be cast to its same type !!?? How this can be possible ?

Below the stack trace :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.roufid.api.dto.user.UserProfileDto cannot be cast to com.roufid.api.dto.user.UserProfileDto
```

#### **Note :** My class is loaded by the same `classloader` and it's `Serializable`.

---

I'm using :

- **Spring Sync : 1.0.0.M1**

Comment: I guess it must have some kind of differences, as this happens during differences related to the serialization. The class is not loaded through a separate library/artifactory that includes a different version of the class itself?

Comment: It's a dto that I created myself in my spring boot project. The artifact was first included by eclipse using Eclipse workspae resolution. The problem still exists even when disabling this option.